# Does Genesis 3 suggest that Adam and Eve's fig-leaf loincloths (v. 7) were unable to cover nakedness, unlike the tunics of skin (v. 21)?

Tags: clothing, tznius-modesty, genesis-bereishith

In [Genesis 3:6-10](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.6-10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the first recorded effect of Adam and Eve's sin is that they realized they were naked. Because of this, they sewed fig leaves together to make loincloths, but this isn't considered enough, as their dialogue with G-d reveals they were still naked. Instead, in [Genesis 3:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), G-d made them tunics of leather.

While there are many contrasts that can be drawn between the fig-leaf loincloths and the tunics of skin, does the text suggest that the fig leaves were unable to cover nakedness (since it still suggests Adam and Eve were naked)? Thanks!

Comment: There is much commentary about exactly what God made for them (gave them actual skin, made clothing from animal fur because it was warm, maybe it was just more resilient in the face of thistles and such. But the Chizkuni also writes, "First Adam and Chavah had made some kind of aprons that could be tied around their loins.(3,7) Now their entire bodies were covered by these tunics"

Comment: Please include the original Hebrew versions: you will immediately see the difference yourself. But still a good question.

Comment: @AlBerko Could you provide a link to a good Hebrew version? If so, thanks!

Comment: Most of us here use https://www.sefaria.org/texts, as the standard version. I truly recommend not to pose a question based solely on English translations, before checking the Hebrew original. For a decent thesaurus, I'd recommend https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow

Comment: @AlBerko Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @AlBerko Jastrow is an Aramaic dictionary

Answer (score 2):

It is clear from the commentators that these clothes were designed to cover all of their body, which the earlier fig-leaves did not (as the verse writes expressly they made only חֲגֹרֹֽת - loincloths).

The [Rashbam](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.21?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashbam_on_Genesis.3.21.1&lang2=bi) notes about these new clothes:

> כתנות עור וילבישם, coats, long enough to cover the whole body.

As to why they were now necessary, refer to [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.21?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Radak_on_Genesis.3.21.1&lang2=bi) who notes that these clothes were now required to provide greater protection as well as factoring in a change in climate outside Gan Eden that these earlier fig leaves did not allow for.

> ויעש ה' אלוקים לאדם ולאשתו כתנות עור, seeing that they had been naked, but had made themselves the aprons made from fig leaves, to cover only their genitals, G-d now provided them with protective clothing for their entire bodies, probably also having in mind different climatic conditions outside the garden....(Sefaria translation)

---

**EDIT**

Since you have slightly edited your question, I will now edit my answer. As I mentioned in my comments, the fig leaves only served to cover their private parts (refer to the Radak that I already quoted as well as the [Sforno](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.11?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Sforno_on_Genesis.3.11.2&lang2=bi)).

Comment: I would also include the first version that says "חגרות" as opposed to later "כתנת".

Comment: @AlBerko - noted and edited.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would 3:10-11 suggest that they were naked even after making the fig-leaf loincloths?

Comment: No they had a loincloth on, but that is not exactly the most modest of attire! i.e. they were still basically naked just their private parts were covered.

Comment: See Sforno - the loincloth just covered their privates https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.11?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Sforno_on_Genesis.3.11.2&lang2=bi (as well as the Radak that I mentioned in my answer above)